# Mailgun only sends partial zip file in Python script when using zipfile zlib python and mailgun

Tags: python, csv, zlib, mailgun, python-zipfile

**EDIT:   I tried to implement gzip but couldn't get it to work with the zipfile library.   The documentation seems to indicate zlib is the only library compatible.**    I also attempted to reinstall zlib.

I have run into a curious issue with a Python script I have created.    The point of the script is to pull some data from SQL server, dump it into a CSV, zip it up (compressed) and email it through the Mailgun API.

if I zip the file without zlib compression, mailgun picks up the entire zipfile (14mb with test data) and emails it off successfully.  I am able to download the zipfile from the email and my local filesystem and open the csv file within without issue.

But as soon as I add the zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED compression method, I encounter issues.   The generated zip gets down to 365kb on my local filesystem and opens up just fine.   But when I look at the generated email, the zip files size is severely truncated and is about 865bytes.  if I attempt to download it and open it, I get "this is not a valid zip file" error from Windows.

Why does Mailgun send the full uncompressed zip, but not the compressed zip even though it opens fine on my filesystem?  One crazy thing I tried even the code is obviously synchronous, was adding pauses between the function calls in case the compression needed more time.  This didn't help.

**Code is below, clipped for brevity.**

```
import pyodbc
import unicodecsv
import time
import requests
import zipfile
import zlib

now = time.localtime(time.time())
today = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%p", now)

filename_sql1 = "SCORM Courses " + today
filename_sql2 = "Non-SCORM Courses " + today

print "ready...."

class ODBCtoCSV(object):

    def __init__(self):

    def getEncodedData (self, doubleList):
        data=struct.pack(len(doubleList) * 'd', *doubleList)
        return base64.b64encode(data)

    def dump(self, sql, filename, include_headers=True):
        f = unicodecsv.writer(file(filename + ".csv", 'wb'))

        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(self.connect_string)
        c = cnxn.cursor()
        c.execute(sql)

        if include_headers:
            f.writerow([d[0] for d in c.description])


            f.writerows(c.fetchall())
            cnxn.close()

def generatereport(s, filename):

    print "Processing %s" % (filename)
    if __name__ == '__main__':

        query = ODBCtoCSV()
        query.dump(s, filename)
        f = open(filename + ".csv", 'rb')


def zippy(filename):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename + ".zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
    zf.write(filename + ".csv")
    zf.close()


def send_notification_message(filename):
    return requests.post(
        "xxxxxxx",
        auth=("api", "xxxx"),
        files=[("attachment", open(filename + ".zip"))],
        data={"from": "xxxxxxx",
              "to": ["xxxxxx"],
              "subject": " Reports are Available",
              "text": "This is an automated message. The reports have run successfully and are available via attachment.",
              "html": "<p><b>This is an automated message.</b></p><p>The reports have run successfully and are available via attachment.</p>",
              "o:tag": "xxxxxx"})        

generatereport(sql1, filename_sql1)
zippy(filename_sql1)
print filename_sql1 + "Succesfully generated"
generatereport(sql2, filename_sql2)
zippy(filename_sql2)
print filename_sql2 + "Succesfully generated"
send_notification_message(filename_sql1)
send_notification_message(filename_sql2)

exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this  by changing the mode file IO mode to'rb' in the Mailgun call.

I am not sure why it worked for uncompressed zip files, and not compressed zipfiles still.    Revised code is below.

```
files=[("attachment", open(filename + ".zip", "rb"))],
```